# Displaying multiple images in Swiper

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Im trying to store images in the swiper by accessing the photos stored in the firebase, the image below is the format of my database. Im using a list for storing photos and displaying them by getting base64. I can only get the first image. I tried using for loop to display multiple images but got no luck.

[image]

```
</View >
        <ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
          {this.state.images.map((u, i) => {
            if ((this.state.images).length != 0) {
              return (
              <Swiper
                renderPagination={renderPagination}
                horizontal={true}
                loop={false}
                key={i}
              > 
              <View style={styles.slide}>
              <Image
               style={styles.image}
               source={(u.photos != undefined && (u.photos).length != 0) ? {uri: "data:image/png;base64," + u.photos[0].base64} : require('../img/Pictogram.png')}
              />
              </View>
              </Swiper>
              );
            }
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

I tried to display multiple image by doing this:
- Making a function which stores the above code
- and inside render i did

```
for (var i=0; i < (u.photos).length; i++) {
    this.new_function;
}
```

but i get error

Comment: Maybe you could try with three Image Tag with uri `u.photos[0].base64` `u.photos[1].base64` `u.photos[2].base64`  ?

Comment: yes but what if the user only adds 2 images won i get error for u.photos[2].base64

Comment: Edit your condition in each Image `(u.photos).length != 0)` to `(u.photos).length >= 1)` `(u.photos).length >= 2)`  ?  But if user could add picture more it couldn't use

Comment: so if i do (u.photos).legnth >=2 i should access u.photos[1].base64?. The only problem is that for instance if i create for images accessing up to 5 images, it will show the three but 4th and 5th it will show my logo which i dont want. Because the user can max uplaod 5 images

Comment: It have so many code to write, I write code in answer, take a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condition like this:

```js
<View>
//... so do 0 and 1
    {(u.photos).length >= 2)?
      <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={(u.photos != undefined && (u.photos).length != 0) ? {uri: "data:image/png;base64," + u.photos[1].base64} : require('../img/Pictogram.png')}
       />  
      :  null;
     }
     {(u.photos).length >= 3)?
      <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={(u.photos != undefined && (u.photos).length != 0) ? {uri: "data:image/png;base64," + u.photos[2].base64} : require('../img/Pictogram.png')}
       />  
      :  null;
     }

//.... and so on to 5 image

</View>
```

And it will not appear the problem.

Maybe is not the best solution, but because you only have max five picture, I think it could work.